# Changing the page size of the site by media query in CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

If I want to change the shape of a website page with a width and height of 600px and change its shape.  Which one should I use?
Max width/height
Or
Min width/height.

I hope you can help me in this matter that I asked about media query in css

Comment: I already has a downvote saying more or the less, but I re-write same because from my "big" experience it's easier to maintain. I prefer min than max. To take your example, at 600px, let say we have a class container, I define .container for under 600. I put a media min-width:600px and define the .container for this. If you have more than 1, in general 3 break points, and several class to change, that's lot easier to read: small to big...

Answer (score 0):

A maximum width can be specified for elements using the max-width property.

When we don't want the width of an element to exceed a certain value, we can use this feature to determine that value for the element.

By using the min-width and max-width properties, you can set a range for the width of an element.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.

The max-width can be specified in length values, like px, cm, etc., or in percent (%) of the containing block, or set to none (this is default. Means that there is no maximum width).

The problem with the  above occurs when the browser window is smaller than the width of the element (500px). The browser then adds a horizontal scrollbar to the page.

Using max-width instead, in this situation, will improve the browser's handling of small windows.